# Moving a file to a new editor window in Kile

Tags: kile, multiple-files

Right now, multiple files are opened as multiple tabs in Kile. But when I have to copy and paste stuff from one file to another, I prefer having the files opened in two different windows.

Is there a way to do this in Kile? Simple dragging of the tabs does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
kile --new
```

will create a new instance of `kile` in a new window.